# Finding the Selected Item in a (On premise SharePoint Farm) SharePoint Document Library using C#

Tags: 2013, web-part

In a on-premise farm, I have a document library displayed by selecting the document library in the Left Hand Navigation which displays the Site Contents.

I select a item from the displayed list.  I want to be able to find the ID of that selected List Item using C#.  There is quite a bit on how to do this in 
JavaScript but I need to do it in C#.

Comment: you can't do this with server side until binding your items to a webpart at grid view as example. are you do something like this ?!  so , How you can know the selected item at client side via server side C# ?

Comment: I am overriding the btn_click event on an application page.  So the user has selected the file. The name of the file is in the title of the application page.  I just need to get the ID of the file selected.

Comment: Nigel, what does SPContext.Current.ListItem.ID return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the ID of a selected item is to use CSOM. You can use the following:

```
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); 
var count = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length;
if (count > 0) { return selectedItems[0].id; } else { return null; }
```

This returns the ID of a selected item. If more than one is selected, this will return the ID of the first one.

There is no way to to do that with server side code (if you are referring to it as C#) as there is no client context.